# Showing an inequality involving Chebyshev and least-squares

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, least-squares

This problem is essentially an estimation problem involving Chebyshev and least-squares approximations.

Suppose we have two $m$-dimensional vectors, $a$ and $b$, where it is known that $\lVert a \rVert_{\infty}$ (Chebyshev) is a better estimate to some estimation problem than $\lVert b \rVert_{\infty}$ (least-squares). We want to show that

\begin{equation}
\lVert b \rVert_{\infty}
\leq 
\sqrt{m}\lVert a \rVert_{\infty}
\end{equation}

using the fact that for all $z$,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \lVert z \rVert_2 \leq \lVert z \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lVert z \rVert_2 \quad (*)
\end{equation}

In this case, I happen to have the solution which goes as:

\begin{equation}
\lVert a \rVert_{\infty} 
\geq
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \lVert a \rVert_2
\geq
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \lVert b \rVert_2
\geq
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \lVert b \rVert_{\infty} 
\end{equation}
and the result follows. Here, the first and the last inequality follow from $(*)$. What is strange to me is the middle inequality.

I begin by describing my work so far involving the middle inequality. From the problem formulation, it is implied that

\begin{equation}
\lVert a \rVert_{\infty} = \gamma\lVert b \rVert_{\infty}
\end{equation}

for some $\gamma\geq 1$. Then, using $(*)$, we can provide lower and upper bounds to this identity as

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \lVert a \rVert_2 \leq \lVert a \rVert_{\infty} = \gamma\lVert b \rVert_{\infty} \leq \gamma\lVert b \rVert_2
\end{equation}

Since $m\geq 1$, we see that we can tighten the lower bound above (in $m$) by choosing $m=1$. Similarly, we can tighten the upper bound below (in $\gamma$) by choosing $\gamma=1$. It follows that:

\begin{equation}
\lVert a \rVert_2 
\leq 
\lVert b \rVert_2
\end{equation}
which is contrary to the middle inequality in the provided solution.

Where does my thinking fail? I am not convinced the solution is correct, but I'd like to be sure. Anyway, your help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious if it's correct to take in $m=1$, considering the dimension of the vectors is fixed in this case (so you might only have $||a||_2\leq\sqrt{m} ||b||_2$).

Comment: @Lazy Lee: Good point.